# Android studio build failed upon adding pdfview library

Tags: android, android-studio, pdf-viewer

I have a working android application to which I have added pdfView library. Upon adding the library adding additional functionality within the app and run on emulator, build failed with following trace:

```
12:02:39 PM Executing tasks: [:app:clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:assembleDebug]
12:03:58 PM Gradle build finished with 1440 error(s) in 1m 18s 260ms
```

Following are the changes I have done: 
1. I have included pdflib library from File -> New -> Import module
2. Added line `compile project(':pdfLib')` to `build.gradle` file.
3. Added some trivial code around using the added lib.

Also received the following exception during runtime:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load vudroid from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/app.com.blynq.player-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/app.com.blynq.player-2, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:355)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:525)
at org.vudroid.core.VuDroidLibraryLoader.load(VuDroidLibraryLoader.java:13)
at org.vudroid.pdfdroid.codec.PdfContext.<clinit>(PdfContext.java:13)
at com.joanzapata.pdfview.DecodingAsyncTask.doInBackground(DecodingAsyncTask.java:50)
at com.joanzapata.pdfview.DecodingAsyncTask.doInBackground(DecodingAsyncTask.java:31)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Please help me with this.

UPDATE:

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.com.blynq.player"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile files('libs/jackson-annotations-2.7.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-core-2.7.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-databind-2.7.4.jar')
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/jpedal_lgpl.jar')
    compile 'com.joanzapata.pdfview:android-pdfview:1.0.4@aar'


}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="app.com.blynq.player.MainActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/blynq_logo"
        />

    <VideoView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        />

    <com.joanzapata.pdfview.PDFView
        android:id="@+id/pdfView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Code where I set pdf in pdfview:

```
videoView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
pdfView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
pdfView.fromFile(new File(mediaPath)).defaultPage(1).enableSwipe(false).load();
```

Comment: What does your layout.xml look like?

Comment: off line download the 'com.joanzapata.pdfview:android-pdfview:1.0.4@aar' .. and set it as 'Module' at your project.

Comment: @AmitabhaBiswas - Tried that too, same errors still remain. Did you work on this lib ?

Comment: @hopeman - added xml to question

Comment: @AMRUTHAKALIVARAPU can you upload your code snippet where you load the PDF?

Comment: right now, I did Build and Run this project Successfully. changed to 'android:name="com.joanzapata.PDFViewActivity" at ManiFest .. and use '    compileSdkVersion 19 ..  buildToolsVersion '21.1.2' ... Itsexecute properly.

Comment: I have tried the exact same thing in a simple and separate project which worked. Problem is when I'm integrating it with working application.

Answer (score 1):

just try this , this will solve your issue.

```
- Replace your compile project(':pdfLib') with
   **'com.joanzapata.pdfview:android-pdfview:1.0.4@aar'** or whatever library you want to add, because adding this type a library, it is
   download the library at run time and build the gradle
   properly,because adding library manually may occur some path issues
   etc.
```

Comment: still have the same exception

Comment: Added to question, please check

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation to the library it says that it is based off of [VuDroid](https://code.google.com/archive/p/vudroid/), which is no longer maintained. The library itself is also no longer maintained; probably as a result of the VuDroid becoming deprecated. I would suggest that you try a library that is still being maintained such as:

- [droidreader](https://code.google.com/archive/p/droidreader/)
- [apv](https://code.google.com/archive/p/apv/)

Alternatively you could load your PDF in a WebView as described [here](http://kylewbanks.com/blog/Loading-PDF-in-Android-WebView).

Comment: I want offline viewer for pdf so cant use webview. Can you please point out to some example implementations for droidreader and apv ?